# Does Warnsdorff’s algorithm for Knight’s tour problem always gives complete tour

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, optimization, backtracking

I have implemented the basic algorithm. easily available but I am not getting the complete tour. 
The visited square never equals N * N;

Comment: Is $n$ large enough? A solution doesn't exist for $n < 5$.

Comment: n = 10 in my case

Comment: For context, wikipedia: [Warnsdorff's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff's_rule)

Answer (score 2):

In general Warnsdorff's rule is just a heuristic that guides the search. It is still possible that the search hits a dead-end and we are forced to backtrack.

So let us consider the $n \times n$ chessboard now.
Warnsdorff's rule (nor any other method) won't find a solution for $n < 5$ as a solution exists precisely when $n \geq 5$. Given that $n \geq 5$, an efficient algorithm based on Warnsdorff's rule is described in [1, Proposition 2.2]. Other independently discovered algorithms that work in linear time are known as well (see e.g., [2]).

---

[1] [Conrad, Axel, Tanja Hindrichs, Hussein Morsy, and Ingo Wegener. "Solution of the knight's Hamiltonian path problem on chessboards." Discrete Applied Mathematics 50, no. 2 (1994): 125-134.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9200170Q)

[2] [Parberry, Ian. "An efficient algorithm for the Knight's tour problem." Discrete Applied Mathematics 73, no. 3 (1997): 251-260.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81964499.pdf)